# Make Webpack use existing source maps

Tags: webpack

I have a couple of existing `.js` and associated `.map.js` (originally built by TypeScript).

Now I'd like Webpack to "serve" those. I'm using this configuration:

```
devtool: "source-map",
module: {
    preLoaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader"}
    ],
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loader: "react-hot"}
    ]
}
```

I got this config from here: [Webpack use existing source map from previous build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795044/webpack-use-existing-source-map-from-previous-build-step)

But all I get are a lot of warnings looking like (even though I have `source-map-loader` installed):

```
WARNING in ./modules/Component.js.map
Module parse failed: /Users/me/project/modules/Component.js.map Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:10)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/me/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/me/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/me/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/me/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/me/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/me/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/me/project/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
 @ ./modules/presentations ^\.\/.*$

[… same warning for each file]
```